# Is there a way to programmatically evaluate a macro?

Tags: objectscript

For example, let us take this code:

```
Method m()
{
    $$$someMacro
}
```

Or:

```
Method m(foo as whatever)
{
   $$$otherMacro(foo)
}
```

Provided that I can extract `someMacro` and `otherMacro` from the code samples above, is there a way to programmatically expand them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Macro can only be resolved at compile time. Since what macro expands into may depend on where in code macro is placed you can't expand one macro without context.

Comment: Not even with a `%Compiler.*` class?

Comment: Since what macro expands into may depend on where in code macro is placed you can't expand one macro without context. And %Compiler is for internal use mainly.